# Adding a controller to my mean.js app seems to automatically fire an api call?

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

Having trouble tracking this down.  I am adding a workflow to user signup in a meanjs app, such that an admin has to invite a user in order for them to be allowed to signup.

For some reason, whenever the invitation form loads, an API call is attempted to `/api/users/invitation` which I did not (as far as I know) ask for, and it doesn't make sense to have one as there's no data it needs.  I assume there's something being auto-wired for me somewhere, but since this 404 causes the page to fail, I need to kill it if I can.

Here's my controller:

```
    (function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('users.admin')
    .controller('InvitationController', InvitationController);

  InvitationController.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', '$window', 'Authentication'];

  function InvitationController($scope, $state, $window, Authentication) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.invitation = {};
    vm.sendMail = sendMail;
    vm.authentication = Authentication;

    function sendMail(isValid) {
      if (!isValid) {
        $scope.$broadcast('show-errors-check-validity', 'vm.invitationForm');

        return false;
      }

      var invitation = vm.invitation;

      // TODO: send to the server
      console.log(invitation);
    }
  }
}());
```

Here's the stateprovider fragment that's relevant:

```
.state('admin.user-invite',{
        url: '/users/invitation',
        templateUrl: 'modules/users/client/views/admin/invite-user.client.view.html',
        controller: 'InvitationController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        data: {
          pageTitle: 'Invite a User'
        }
      })
```

Any idea where else to look?  This is my first app using the MEAN.js framework, though I've used angular quite a bit in the past.

Comment: It'll be in the template somewhere, most likely `ng-change`; if you debug it and go up the call stack you should be able to get to the element that triggered the event.

It'll probably be something like you've set a boolean somewhere and ng-required sets it to undefined if it's false, or something like that, which triggers the call.

Comment: Not that I can find.  No ng-change in any of the templates loading in the page.  Looking at the call stack on the error shows nothing but angular.js code, nothing native to my project.  I'm not sure what you mean about triggering 'the event', nor do I understand where you're coming from wrt 'ng-required'.

Comment: I mean, I've searched through every file in my project for anything that builds that URL, and I can't find it...

Comment: If Angular is calling your code and you're not doing it then it could be through a DOM event on an element. So by event, I meant whichever event triggered one of Angular's in-built directives. Angular doesn't just randomly call functions, so somewhere in your template or another directive you have to be using `send` somewhere. Have you called any other controller functions `send`? Or used the wrong syntax with an isolated scope? Or used `{{send()}}` in `ng-click` when you should've used just `send()`?

Comment: No, I know angular doesn't randomly make API calls; my assumption is that it's something in the default MEAN.js project that I haven't found yet.  I also searched for any code involving the word `send`, and there's nothing in my project that uses that word at all except for in server-side responses.

Comment: Another bit of evidence, if I change the URL in the state config object, the API call changes too (so whatever is doing it is building the URL based on the convention of prepending /api to the current path.

Answer (score 0):

OK, took me an embarrassingly long time to realize this, but it turns out the URL matching was the actual problem at hand.

I should have included my full set of client-side routes in the question, as what was happening was that `/users/invitation` was actually the last route declared.  Turns out, `/users/:userId` was matching against that, and so the router was interpreting `invitations` as a userId, and the matching route had a resolver function which was in turn trying to call my server-side users api.

Now the part that is still baking my noodle (though it's less important in that my current problem is solved) is why would the route matcher do that, but still render the template that I'd assigned to the `/users/invitation` route?  The fact that it was doing that certainly made the debugging longer, as the matched route has a very different template assigned to it than my intended route.

Answer (score -1):

Can you examine network requests in developer tools. It could be a request to '/users/invitation', but the '/api' part is getting prefixed on the server side code (prefixed to router??).